# count each occurrences when date falls within a range

Tags: python, django, postgresql, orm

I am trying to count each time the value of month in `created_on` falls within different months, using this django orm below:

```
    result_qs = Model.objects.all().annotate(
        spring=Count(Case(When(ExtractMonth("created_on") in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], then=1))),
        summer=Count(Case(When(ExtractMonth("created_on") in [6, 7], then=1))),
        fall=Count(Case(When(ExtractMonth("created_on") in [8, 9, 10, 11, 12], then=1))),
        year=ExtractYear("created_on")
)
```

I'm getting the error

> When() supports a Q object, a boolean expression, or lookups as a
> condition.

When I apply `Q` notations to one of the cases, such as:

```
spring=Count(Case(When(Q(ExtractMonth("created_on") in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], then=1)))),
```

> cannot unpack non-iterable bool object

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
result_qs = Model.objects.all().annotate(
        spring=Count(Case(When(created_on__month__in=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], then=1))),
        summer=Count(Case(When(created_on__month__in=[6, 7], then=1))),
        fall=Count(Case(When(created_on__month__in=[8, 9, 10, 11, 12], then=1))),
        year=ExtractYear("created_on")
)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks. I didn't know `__month__` was possible.

Comment: Glad I could help. There are also for the other dates: `__day`, `__year`, `__week`